# Write a SQL statement to show minimum of a total revenue of each department

Tags: sql

I figured out the total revenue of each department from Cape_codd, but I want to show highest and lowest revenue of each department. Would anyone help ?

```
SELECT Warehouse, SUM(ExtendedPrice) AS TotalRevenue
FROM INVENTORY, ORDER_ITEM
GROUP BY Warehouse
```

Table

```
Department    TotalRevenue
Camping       2360.00
Climbing      2360.00
Water Sports  4720.00
```

for max -- I want to show Water Sport department and its revenue
for min -- I want to show lowest of total revenue associated with department ( show 2 departments if they have the same lowest revenue)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Sql Server` use `Top 1 with ties`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties Warehouse,
                       Sum(ExtendedPrice) AS TotalRevenue
FROM   INVENTORY,
       ORDER_ITEM
GROUP  BY Warehouse
ORDER  BY TotalRevenue ASC
```

else

```
SELECT Warehouse,
       Sum(ExtendedPrice) AS TotalRevenue
FROM   INVENTORY,
       ORDER_ITEM
GROUP  BY Warehouse
HAVING Sum(ExtendedPrice) = (SELECT TOP 1 Sum(ExtendedPrice) AS TotalRevenue
                             FROM   INVENTORY,
                                    ORDER_ITEM
                             GROUP  BY Warehouse
                             ORDER  BY TotalRevenue ASC)
```

Based on the `RDMBS` you are using you need to change the `TOP 1` in `subquery` to `LIMIT 1` or `ROWNUM`...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just change to TOP 2 to show lowest revenue of 2 departments because they have the same lowest revenue

Comment: @user3500297 No you should not do that. If you have `tie` hen it will return the rows with same `TotalRevenue`

Comment: So how do I show multiple results if the output is more than 1

Comment: @user3500297 - Did you execute my query